# init of slice in struct

Tags: go, slice

I am struggling with the initiation of a slice in a struct (GO-language). This may be easy, but still I can not solve it. I get below error

```
./prog.go:11:1: syntax error: unexpected var, expecting field name or embedded type
./prog.go:25:2: no new variables on left side of :=
./prog.go:26:2: non-name g.s on left side of :=
```

I believe that `s` should be declared as part of the struct, so I wonder why I get that error. Someone got some advice?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type node struct {
    value int
}

type graph struct {
    nodes, edges int
    s            []int
}

func main() {
    g := graphCreate()
}

func input(tname string) (number int) {
    fmt.Println("input a number of " + tname)
    fmt.Scan(&number)
    return
}

func graphCreate() (g graph) {
    g := graph{input("nodes"), input("edges")}
    g.s = make([]int, 100)
    return
}
```

Comment: Compiler errors you mentioned are clearly saying what’s the error. You should replace those two `:=`s with `=`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a few errors :

- `g.s` is already defined by the type `graph` when `g` is of type `graph`. So it's not a "new variable"
- you can't use `var` inside a type declaration
- you have `g` already declared (as a return type) in your `graphCreate` function
- when you write a literal struct, [you must pass none or all the field values or name them](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals)
- you must use the variables you declare

here's a compiling code :

```
package main

import "fmt"

type node struct {
    value int
}

type graph struct {
    nodes, edges int
    s            []int // <= there was var here
}

func main() {
    graphCreate() // <= g wasn't used
}

func input(tname string) (number int) {
    fmt.Println("input a number of " + tname)
    fmt.Scan(&number)
    return
}

func graphCreate() (g graph) { // <= g is declared here
    g = graph{nodes:input("nodes"), edges:input("edges")} // <= name the fields
    g.s = make([]int, 100) // <= g.s is already a known name
    return
}
```

Comment: what about the unexpected var, expecting }?

Comment: thank you. I am need to Go so these answers are very useful to me:)

Comment: You probably don't need the `g.s = make([]int, 100)` line. A nil slice (the zero-value) works as an empty slice, and you can `append` to it just fine. The only reasons to do otherwise is if you're sure you know the final size up front and care about maximum efficiency, or you want to populate the slice randomly rather than sequentially.